# mysql - Set temporary variable to store more than 1 records?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in mysql to have a temporary variable store more than 1 records? For example, a very simple query:

```
set @Root = (select N from Tree where P is NULL); -- stores one value
set @Leaf1 = (select N from Tree where P=@Root); -- this needs two values
```

For the purpose of data reproduction, here's the table that I would like to have:

```
N P Value
1 2 Inner
3 2 Inner
5 6 Inne
7 6 Inner
2 4 Leaf
6 4 Leaf
4 15 Leaf
8 9 Inner
10 9 Inner
12 13 Inner
14 13 Inner
9 11 Leaf
13 11 Leaf
11 15 Leaf
15 NULL Root
```

And here's the query I wrote:

```
set @Root = (select N from pract_db.Tree where P is Null);
set @Leaf1 = (select GROUP_CONCAT(N) from pract_db.Tree where P=@Root);
set @Leaf2 = (select GROUP_CONCAT(N) from pract_db.Tree where P=@Leaf1);

select N, P,
    CASE when (P is NULL) then "Root"
         when (P=@Root) then "Leaf"
         when (P=@Leaf1) then "Leaf"
         when (P=@Leaf2) then "Leaf"
         else "Inner"
    end as Value
from pract_db.Tree;
```

The problem with this query is that it is assigning leaves based only on the first value of GROUP_CONCAT (i.e. getting leaves only for 4).

Edit: So I'm able to use GROUP_CONCAT but still not getting expected results.

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT (or JSON_ARRAYAGG) and store multiple-valued CSV/JSON in your variable.

Comment: Please what your desired result, may be it can be reached without temporary variables. Also provide MySQL version

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Solution can be written without temporary variables. However this is how I would like to solve it.

Comment: Added some more lines with the query I executed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a temp table for this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTree select N from Tree where P=@Root LIMIT 0;
```

This one:

```
set @Leaf1 = (select GROUP_CONCAT(N) from pract_db.Tree where P=@Root);
```

Works (but wrongly) because just selecting 1 aggregate function as column always returns 1 and only row. Same for selecting many aggregate functions. 1 row is returned.

But you probably need to group to get all values:

```
select N, GROUP_CONCAT(N) from pract_db.Tree where P=@Root group by N;
```

So most likely you need a temp table here as well.

Comment: Thanks but I was able to solve this without temporary variables.